# How do I create a project file for Sphinx4 in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I downloaded *Sphinx 4 beta* version 3 [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinx4/1.0%20beta3/sphinx4-1.0beta3-src.zip/download) but when I try to import into Eclipse it says there are no valid project files in it's folder

How do I create a valid project file for this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the downloaded folder for a project.xml. If there is a project you can import the containing folder via "import" -> "existing project". If there is no project.xml you cannot import it as a project! Use "import" -> "file system" instead of "import" -> "existing project".

This will start the project wizard.

Comment: there is no project.xml either. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: as I wrote. if there is no project.xml you have to import from file system / source.

Answer (score 1):

Try `New` -> `Project` -> `from existing source`

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx4 can not be imported as a project in Eclipse. You have to create a new project and copy the contents of Sphinx4 into that directory, then add all those files to a project.

Unfortunately you will still have to use ant to build the project. It probably is possible to integrate it with eclipse, though I haven't been able to do that (I haven't tried too hard though).

Comment: actually I can import Sphinx 4 beta 6 (trying to compile it using using eclipse is a different problem however). I thought I would be able to do so with the older versions of Sphinx 4 beta as well, but it doesn't import

Comment: @user13267 I am not certain which version I was using; I managed to use Eclipse as IDE with Sphinx, but I was never able to compile it properly without `Ant` script. Ant integrates with Eclipse, so it wasn't much of a problem.